# Questions about empty cmake FIND macros

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, cmake

I have a macro that looks like this

```
MACRO(FFMPEG_FIND varname shortname headername)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "FFMPEG_${varname}_LIBRARIES: ${FFMPEG_${varname}_LIBRARIES}")
    MESSAGE(STATUS "FFMPEG_${varname}_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${FFMPEG_${varname}_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
ENDMACRO(FFMPEG_FIND)
```

which is called like this:

```
FFMPEG_FIND(LIBAVFORMAT avformat avformat.h)
FFMPEG_FIND(LIBAVDEVICE avdevice avdevice.h)
FFMPEG_FIND(LIBAVCODEC  avcodec  avcodec.h)
FFMPEG_FIND(LIBAVUTIL   avutil   avutil.h)
FFMPEG_FIND(LIBSWSCALE  swscale  swscale.h)  # not sure about the header to look for here.
```

Which will give us the output of

```
-- FFMPEG_LIBAVFORMAT_LIBRARIES: F:/Dev/Lib/ffmpeg-20140507-git-4cdea92-win32-de
v/lib/avformat.lib
-- FFMPEG_LIBAVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIRS: F:/Dev/Lib/ffmpeg-2.2.1
-- FFMPEG_LIBAVDEVICE_LIBRARIES: F:/Dev/Lib/ffmpeg-20140507-git-4cdea92-win32-de
v/lib/avdevice.lib
-- FFMPEG_LIBAVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIRS: F:/Dev/Lib/ffmpeg-2.2.1
-- FFMPEG_LIBAVCODEC_LIBRARIES: F:/Dev/Lib/ffmpeg-20140507-git-4cdea92-win32-dev
/lib/avcodec.lib
-- FFMPEG_LIBAVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIRS: F:/Dev/Lib/ffmpeg-2.2.1
-- FFMPEG_LIBAVUTIL_LIBRARIES: F:/Dev/Lib/ffmpeg-20140507-git-4cdea92-win32-dev/
lib/avutil.lib
-- FFMPEG_LIBAVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIRS: F:/Dev/Lib/ffmpeg-2.2.1
-- FFMPEG_LIBSWSCALE_LIBRARIES: F:/Dev/Lib/ffmpeg-20140507-git-4cdea92-win32-dev
/lib/swscale.lib
-- FFMPEG_LIBSWSCALE_INCLUDE_DIRS: F:/Dev/Lib/ffmpeg-2.2.1
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

My first question is how is cmake even finding the libraries on my hard drive while the FIND macro is essentially empty. The more important question being, why is `INCLUDE_DIRS` set to `F:/Dev/Lib/ffmpeg-2.2.1` which is a path that doesn't even exist (there is no ffmpeg-2.2.1 folder in F:/Dev/Lib), as it should be pointing to `F:/Dev/Lib/ffmpeg-20140507-git-4cdea92-win32-dev/include`

Comment: Your macro doesn't find anything, it just prints values from `CMakeCache.txt`. You didn't provide any code to determine where these values are coming from.

Comment: That is the answer I'm looking for actually, I didn't know cmake caches these variables. I think I know where to look for next now, thanks for clearing this up. (by the way if you can put that as an answer I would love to accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macro doesn't find anything, it just prints values from `CMakeCache.txt`, which is a persistent storage betweeen `cmake` invocations (or `configure` step in GUI). Your FFMPEG-related values was set by previous `cmake` call and now cmake prints them.

Cache values can be changed by running `cmake -DVAR=VALUE .` in your build directory.